# Convert an array into map using stream

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have a list of integers  `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to convert it into a map after applying a multiplication function (*5) like this:

```
 {1 = 5, 2 = 10, 3 = 15, 4 = 20, 5 = 25}
```

I was able to use stream and use map function to perform the multiplication but I'm confused about how to convert the result into a map.

```
myList.stream().map(n -> n * 5).collect( ... )
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Don't apply the multiplication before mapping but apply it to the value extraction passed to the collector, e.g. `Collectors.toMap( v -> v, v -> v * 5)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current stream pipeline converts the original values to new values, so you can't collect it into a `Map` that contains both the original values and the new values.

You can achieve it if instead of `map` you use `.collect(Collectors.toMap())` and perform the multiplication in `toMap()`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map =
    myList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                    n -> n * 5));
```

In you still want to use `map`, you can retain the original values by converting each of them to a `Map.Entry`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map =
    myList.stream()
          .map (n -> new SimpleEntry<> (n, n * 5))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Thank you. Multiplication was actually the simplification of the problem. What if I have to call some function instead of multiplication. Can I still use - 

`myList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                    someFunction()));`

Comment: @user3828862 of course, but it should probably be `n -> someFunction(n)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Another question if you don't mind.
If I want to return my struct like

`{1={value=5}, 2={value=10), 3={value=15), 4={value=20), 5={value=25)}`

i.e. Map<key, object>

One way to do it is I make my someFunction(n) return a map i.e. `{value = n*5}`

Is there another way where I don't have to change my function someFunction(n)

Comment: @user3828862 I don't understand. Why would `someFunction(n)` return a `Map`? It should just return the value that should be mapped to `n`.

Comment: As I mentioned, If this is the output I'm looking for,

`{1={"value"=5}, 2={"value"=10), 3={"value"=15), 4={"value"=20), 5={"value"=25)}`

If `someFunction(n)`  just returns a value called `output` then we how can we create `n = {"value" = output}` in `Collectors.toMap`

Comment: @user3828862 what is `{value=25}`? Is it a `Map`? What are the key and value of that `Map`? Should your output be a `Map<Integer,Map<Something,SomethingElse>>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) and pass any function for the value e.g. by using a UnaryOperator as shown below:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnaryOperator<Integer> add = x -> x + 5;
        UnaryOperator<Integer> mutiply = x -> x * 5;
        UnaryOperator<Integer> factorial = x -> factorial(x);

        // Test
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), add));
        Map<Integer, Integer> map2 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), mutiply));
        Map<Integer, Integer> map3 = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), factorial));

        System.out.println(map1);
        System.out.println(map2);
        System.out.println(map3);
    }

    static int getValue(int x, UnaryOperator<Integer> function) {
        return function.apply(x);
    }

    static int factorial(int x) {
        if (x <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1=6, 2=7, 3=8, 4=9, 5=10}
{1=5, 2=10, 3=15, 4=20, 5=25}
{1=1, 2=2, 3=6, 4=24, 5=120}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays
        .stream(nums)
        .boxed() // this
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The .collect(Collectors.toMap()) is what you need. Without the .map.

myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(n-> n, n -> n * 5))